# Elastic Search APM server setup for NodeJs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm Integrating ElasticSearch,Kibana APM in to My NodeJs Application.I have installed apm-server and setup `apm-server.yml` as bellow

`output.elasticsearch:
hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "elastic"`

then run `service apm-server start` .

**configured Node side as bellow**

`var apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({
    serviceName: 'MyApp',
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8200'
  })`

**Checked status**

**APM Server status : You have correctly setup APM Server**

**Agent status : Data successfully received from one or more agents**

It's worked last night and showed charts on kibana dashboard.but now i'm getting bellow error on my Console and `No services found` on dashboard

`[ERROR] APM Server transport error (ECONNREFUSED): connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200`

Comment: Seems like your node server on http://localhost:8200 is not running.

Comment: My Node App is running on port 8001.